# Measuring parameters for the Universal Scalability Law for a NodeJS application running in docker

Tags: node.js, performance, docker, performance-testing, measure

For my bachelors thesis (Software & Information Engineering) I want to apply the Universal Scalability Law (Neil J. Gunther, 1993) on a NodeJS microservices application running in a docker environment (current situation) and running in a kubernetes environment (new situation).

The Universal Scalability Law: X(N) = λN / 1 + (σ(N − 1) + κN(N − 1))

σ(N − 1) = fraction of resistance due to serialization/queuing

κN(N − 1) = fraction of resistance due to crosstalk/coherency

Things I want to measure:

1. Throughput of the application running in docker with single containers.
2. Throughput of the application running in kubernetes with one pod, two pods (load balanced) and three pods (load balanced). (One pod will contain all containers of the microservice)
3. Because I know the throughput of the application with different amount of kubernetes pods (step 1 and 2), I can calculate the total resistance. But how do I know which part of this resistance is due to serialization/queuing and which part is due to crosstalk/coherency? Are there tools to measure this?

I am totally new to The Universal Scalability Law and not a genius at math, I found out about this law through this paper: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/498921/eBooks/scalability_new.pdf

Comment: You're probably not going to get readymade tools which offers you the calculations you're looking for, However, Prometheus (https://prometheus.io/) shows metrics per operation. you could potentially write a script which queries prometheus selectively and calculate the stuff yourself. Apart from prometheus you can find so many different tools which does the same, but prometheus is quite popular. You can go a step ahead and setup a Grafana Dashboard (https://grafana.com/) which queries prometheus and visualises live metrics